# Update css values dynamically in a php script

Tags: php, css, smarty

I am writing a navigation menu using php and smarty. I need to modify some values in my stylesheets dynamically. For example, for each iteration, id="nav1" should be changed to id="nav1", id="nav2", id="nav3" and so on. I could use $caty@index (index array) but it starts from 0.

In addition, in submenus, the first list item should only hold the class="topli" and the rest should not include class="topli" and they should look like this:

```
<li>
  <a href="categories.php?id={$inc.catid|stripslashes}">{$inc.name|stripslashes|replace:" ":"&nbsp;"}</a>
</li>
```

The actual script:

```
<div id="topnav_container">
    <div id="topnav">
        <ul id="nav">
        {foreach from=$categori item=caty}
        {assign var="ifavaible" value=$caty@total}
        {if  $caty@index < {$toplinks}}
        {if $rewritemod == 2}

            <li class="nav-item" id="nav1">
                <a href="categories.php?id={$caty.catid|stripslashes}">{$caty.name|stripslashes}</a>
        {/if}

                <div>
                    <ul class="child">
                    {foreach from=$subcat item=inc}
                    {if $inc.cord neq 0 && $caty.catid eq $inc.parent}
                    {if $rewritemod == 2}

                        <li class="topli">
                            <a href="categories.php?id={$inc.catid|stripslashes}">{$inc.name|stripslashes|replace:" ":"&nbsp;"}</a>
                        </li>
                    {/if}
                    {/if}
                    {/foreach}

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        {/if}
        {/foreach}

        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- end: #topnav -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First question, how to get "nav1", "nav2", "nav3" and so forth. You could use `@ iteration` which starts from 1 unlike `@index` which starts from 0

```
<li class="nav-item" id="nav{$caty@iteration}">
```

Second question, how to apply class only to the first element. The traditional way would be to use the `@first` keyword, which is `true` when you are iterating the first element of the array, however you seem to have a lot of if-statements going on *within* the loop, so I wouldn't rely on that. Instead you could save a parameter if the class has been set, like so

```
{foreach from=$subcat item=inc}

{$first = true}

{if $inc.cord neq 0 && $caty.catid eq $inc.parent}
{if $rewritemod == 2}

    <li {if $first}class="topli"{/if}>
        <a href="categories.php?id={$inc.catid|stripslashes}">{$inc.name|stripslashes|replace:" ":"&nbsp;"}</a>
    </li>
    {$first = false}
{/if}
{/if}
{/foreach}
```